# basic URL Rewriting in php issue

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have url coming on my web page like:

> www.abc.com/product_list.php?id=12&pId=1&gpId=0

I want it to show like:

> www.abc.com/product_list.php/12/1/0

i know this is very basic question but i am new in php.

your help will be really appreciated.

**I did experiment like this but its not working: (in my htaccess file by googling)**

```
RewriteRule ^product_list.php /product_list.php/id=$1/pId=$2/gpId=$3 [NC]
```

**My .htaccessfile:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (google|yahoo|msn|aol|bing) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (google|yahoo|msn|aol|bing)
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ hamper-anastassia.php?$1 [L]



RewriteRule index.html$ /index.php
RewriteRule about.html$ /about.php
RewriteRule products.html$ /products.php
RewriteRule partners.html$ /partners.php
RewriteRule career.html$ /career.php
RewriteRule contact.html$ /contact.php

RewriteRule products_(.*)_(.*).html$ products.php?id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^product_list/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /product_list.php?id=$1&pId=$2&gpId=$3 [NC]
```

Comment: You've got the second part right, but you need to define the first part (the condition) and capture the data for `$1` `$2` `$3`.

Comment: can you guide me how to do that? i am new in php

Comment: Are `product_list.php` and `.htacess` in the same directory i.e. `DocumentRoot` of your site. If yes then try placing last rule as first rule below `RewriteEngine On` line and retest with `http://example.com/product_list/12/1/0`

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the .php

A simple example to capture the first parameter.

`RewriteRule    ^products/([0-9]+)/?$    show_a_product.php?product_id=$1`

More here 
https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

Basically every pairing of brackets catches a variable, this is where the `$1`, `$2`, `$3` comes from.

```
RewriteRule    ^product_list.php/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$    /product_list.php?id=$1&pId=$2&gpId=$3    [NC]
```

As Geoffrey mentions you could go one step further and remove the need for `.php` but that's up to you, e.g:

```
RewriteRule    ^product_list/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$    /product_list.php?id=$1&pId=$2&gpId=$3    [NC]
```

Meaning you could visit `/product_list/12/1/0`

Comment: not working, i am writing this in root .htaccess file but my top url remain same not changing automatically.

Comment: Make sure you have mod rewrite enabled and running. The above should work. You should also have a read through this to improve your understanding: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: when i visit: /product_list/12/1/0   it gives me page not found error

Answer (score 0):

Please remove/comment everything in your .htaccess file then type only these two statements

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ products.php?id=$1&pid=$2&gpid=$3
```

Your url should be like this:

```
/products/1/2/3
```

If your still getting and error check your mod_rewrite configurations